# C++ int massives

Tags: c++, int

I tried to solve well-known task " pile of stones " with sorting and throwing weights to different massives. But programm works weird now, it shows correct massives and summs of elements in debug mode , but in Run it shows different, incorrect answer.

here's the code:

```
void Sort(int pile[],int N)
{
    int tmp=0;
    for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(pile[j]<pile[j+1])
            {
                tmp=pile[j];
                pile[j]=pile[j+1];
                pile[j+1]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Show(int pile[], int N)
{
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout<<pile[i]<<"  ";
    }
}

void Alternate()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int *pile , *LHeap, *RHeap, N=0, RCount=0, LCount=0, RIter=1,LIter=1;
        cout<<Rus("\nВведите количество камней: ");
        cin>>N;
        ///dynamic memory for N-size mass
        pile=new int(N);
        LHeap=new int(N);
        RHeap=new int(N);
        ///App close if 0 size of mass entered
        if(N==0) break;
        else
        {
            cout<<Rus("Введите вес всех камней\n");
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                cin>>pile[i];
            }

            Sort(pile, N);
            Show(pile, N);
            ///make first elements of heap's equal to 1 and 2 elements of pile
            ///Count'z to count the current size of mass
            LHeap[0]=pile[0];
            LCount+=pile[0];

            RHeap[0]=pile[1];
            RCount+=pile[1];
            ///fulfill both massive
            for(int i=2; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(LCount<=RCount)
                {
                    LHeap[LIter]=pile[i];
                    LIter++;
                    LCount+=pile[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    RHeap[RIter]=pile[i];
                    RIter++;
                    RCount+=pile[i];
                }
            }

            cout<<Rus("\nкуча 1: ");
            Show(LHeap,LIter);
            cout<<Rus("\nкуча 2: ");
            Show(RHeap,RIter);
            cout<<Rus("\nСумы в кучах: ")<<LCount<<"  "<<RCount<<endl;

        }

    }


}

int main()
{
    //Primitive();
    Alternate();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use C++11 and its [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). Life is too short to reinvent your poor sorting routine (and bubble sort is a poor sorting algorithm). Then, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11` with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Memory leaks, everywhere memory leaks. - By the way, I wish comment vote down would be possible. + I cannot spot a question in your "question".

Comment: okay, sorry for my mistakes all along, but im new here and in programming, didnt adapted yet

Comment: so a question was: why answers are differs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting different results because your program is undefined.

This

```
new int(N)
```

allocates *one* `int` with the value `N`.
Indexing any index other than 0 from that pointer is undefined.

To allocate an array, use

```
new int[N]
```

Comment: I'll add that it probably works in debug mode because the compiler allocates more memory so if you over-run / go out of bounds, it doesn't instantly corrupt everything else. e.g. with an off by one error on array access.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::vector`.

Comment: wow, that worked. Thanks alot :)
You just poked my face into my stupidity and inattensivenes

Comment: @prazza Don't feel stupid, everyone's made the same mistake at least once.